# Can I re-apply for a Swiss Schengen visa immediately after it was refused or do I need to wait 30 days?

Tags: schengen, visa-refusals, schengen-visas

Is it true that you have to wait 30 days before re-applying for a Schengen visa for Switzerland after being rejected?

I can’t find any evidence of this anywhere but this article and there’s no reference for this either:
https://www.atlys.com/post/schengen-visa-application-denied

I think I understand the mistake I made with my application so this is why I wish to reapply.

Comment: AFAIK there is no formal limit. Please see [How to Reapply for a Schengen Visa After Rejection](https://visasassociation.com/reapply-for-schengen-visa/). There is more info there than just re-applying.

Comment: I'm curious what you think the mistake was.

Comment: Ask a friend to critically review your application. You should not do again errors. Really. And in any case, think if your past mistake could be seen as malicious (hiding some important information, or misrepresenting data). Your next application will be check carefully and every rejection is going to affect your probability for most visa in most countries. In any case: take time to really review and have a perfect application.

Comment: @GiacomoCatenazzi all good advice, but from the asker's previous question we know that she is a US citizen and that the application is actually for her husband who holds a US green card, has had a few previous Schengen visas, is employed by Microsoft, and will likely be a US citizen before a subsequent trip to the Schengen area is contemplated.  This raises two points: first, the refusal is baffling, so the likely explanation is indeed some mistake in the application, and second, a second refusal will be less of a problem since subsequent trips will not require a visa.

Comment: We’re going to take a chance and reapply for a Schengen visa again with Switzerland.  We’ve provided an extremely detailed new itinerary and more information about green card and citizenship status next year, income, assets, a statement from his immigration lawyer, etc.

Comment: @phoog - is it possible that it was refused because, with his shiny new US passport, he won't need one?

Comment: @simonatrcl that seems like a bad reason to refuse the visa given that he won't yet have the US passport at the time of the proposed trip for which the visa application was made.

Answer (score 4):

Yes you can; there is no waiting period required as far as I know. The general advice about applying, particularly after a rejection, does not change.